# Collision of two sprites in separate lists

Tags: c++, collision-detection, sfml

I try to program a top-down-shooter in SFML at the moment, but ran into a problem. I'm quite new to C++ and programming in general, so please excuse messy code and/or overly complicated solutions.

I have two `std::list`s, one containing the randomly spawning enemies, the other containing the bullets I fired. When a bullet hits a enemy, both of them should get erased, but it doesn't work.

Here's the problem-part of my code:

```
for(MonsterIt = MonsterList.begin(); MonsterIt != MonsterList.end(); MonsterIt++)
{

    //Here would be Monster-Movement

    //Collision Monster-Player (MonsterIt = iterator of MonsterList)
    if ((MonsterIt -> getPosition().x + 25) >= PlayerX - 25 && 
        (MonsterIt -> getPosition().x - 25) <= PlayerX + 25 &&
        (MonsterIt -> getPosition().y + 25) >= PlayerY - 25 && 
        (MonsterIt -> getPosition().y - 25) <= PlayerY + 25   )
    {
        MonsterList.erase(MonsterIt);
        break;              
    }


        window.draw(*MonsterIt);
}
```

That's the way I've done collision between Monster and Player. That worked fine, so I tried the same with Monsters and Lasers:

```
for(LaserIt = LaserList.begin(); LaserIt != LaserList.end(); LaserIt++)
{

    //Here would be "Laser-Movement"

    //Collision-Laser                               // Doesn't work
    if ((MonsterIt -> getPosition().x + 25) >=      //
        (LaserIt   -> getPosition().x - 7) &&       //
        (MonsterIt -> getPosition().x - 25) <=      //
        (LaserIt   -> getPosition().x + 7) &&       //
        (MonsterIt -> getPosition().y + 25) >=      //
        (LaserIt   -> getPosition().y - 7) &&       //
        (MonsterIt -> getPosition().y - 25) <=      //
        (LaserIt   -> getPosition().x + 7))         //
    {                                               //
        MonsterList.erase(MonsterIt);               //
                                                    //
        LaserList.erase(LaserIt);                   //
                                                    //
        break;                                      //
    }                                               //  

    window.draw(*LaserIt);
}
```

When I put in the part of code I marked (with // on right side) I get a "list iterator not dereferencable"-error while debugging as soon as I shoot. When I cut out said code it runs fine (I can shoot, walk into monsters and they disappear, etc.). Because of that I guess the rest of my code is working.

So, is collision between iterators of different lists even possible?
And if so, how do I do it?

If you need more information or code, please ask. I'd be glad for your help...

Comment: How do you know `MonsterIt` is a valid iterator in the second fragment?

Comment: That's my problem. I guess it's not valid and that's why it doesn't work. But how can I make a collision between a Monster, which is part of MonsterList, and a Laser-Shot, which is part of LaserList? Like I said, I'm quite new to c++. As far as I understood the iterator, here MonsterIt, is the "name" of one Member of the List. Is that true?

Comment: Not really. `MonsterIt` is the name of a variable that "points" to a monster (`MonsterIt` is an iterator, not a monster).

Comment: Does MonsterIt point to the Memory-adress of a Monster or to the content of that adress?

Comment: If you need to find collisions between *all* monsters and *all* laser-shots, you perhaps need nested loops, e.g. `for (MonsterIt = ...) { for (LaserIt = ...) { ... } }`. Do you have this or similar structure? If yes, here's the problem: you erase `MonsterIt` and then continue with the outer loop, i.e. increment the erased iterator. You need to redesign the outer loop to avoid this. First move to the next element, then erase the needed element. Better yet, learn and use `std::remove_if`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iterator you use is not valid.

There are several solutions to your problems. First one:

```
for(MonsterIt = MonsterList.begin(); MonsterIt != MonsterList.end(); MonsterIt++)
{
    //Here would be Monster-Movement

    //Collision Monster-Player (MonsterIt = iterator of MonsterList)

    // Collision with laser, inside the loop for monsters
    for(LaserIt = LaserList.begin(); LaserIt != LaserList.end(); LaserIt++)
    {
    }

    window.draw(*MonsterIt);
}
```

This solution is not really C++ish. With OOP, you can have a much clearer code:

```
class Player
{
    public:
        int X, Y; // for code simplicity on SO.
};
// ...

Player player;
for(MonsterIt = MonsterList.begin(); MonsterIt != MonsterList.end(); MonsterIt++)
{
    MonsterIt->update(player,LaserList);
    if(!MonsterIt->isAlive())
    {
        // Remove monster from list *without* break
    }
}
```

Then, `Monster` is a class like the following:
    class Monster
    {
            bool alive;
        public:
            bool isAlive() const { return alive; }

```
        bool collideWithPlayer(Player p) const
        {
            // Returns whether it collide with player
            // ...
        }

        bool collideWithLaser(Laser l) const
        {
            // Returns whether it collide with one laser
            // ...
        }

        bool collideWithLasers(LaserList l) const
        {
            for(LaserIt = LaserList.begin(); LaserIt != LaserList.end(); LaserIt++)
                if(collideWithLaser(*LaserIt))
                    return true;
            return false;
        }


        void update(Player p, LaserList l)
        {
            if(collideWithPlayer(p) || collideWithLasers(l))
                alive = false;
            else
                window.draw(this);
        }
};
```